# Best way to manage concurrency on topic editing

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I have some data in my Website (written on PHP and MySql) which users can edit.

As you know, if a `User A` open the edit box, and during this editing another `User B` open the same edit box, one of these user will loose his revisions (the one who finish first).

So I implemented a sort of Access Time (20 minuts) for the first user who try to edit. This is the code :

```
$dateBlock=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$update=mysql_query("UPDATE tracklist SET block_user='".$_SESSION['nickname']."', block_date='".$dateBlock."' WHERE 
(trackid='".$_GET['trackid']."' AND block_user='') or 
(trackid='".$_GET['trackid']."' AND block_user='".$_SESSION['nickname']."') or 
(trackid='".$_GET['trackid']."' AND block_date<SUBTIME('".$dateBlock."', '0:20'))",$mydb);
$updatedRows=mysql_affected_rows();
if($updatedRows==0) $messaggio="Sorry but another User is editing this tracklist";
```

But I don't like so much this kind of approch.

What can you suggest to me? For example what's the approch on stackoverflow?

Comment: By using $_GET["trackid"] in your SQL query you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: No man don't worry : I already filtered all variables:) For example `$_GET["trackid"]` can be only `ctype_digit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to choose between two options:

As one answer suggested: Lock the textbox until it is submitted, hereby ruling out that anybody else can edit it in that time

Keep track of different versions as the other user suggested, by instead of always updating the content, always adding new content with a field that indicates the version so people can than see different versions, or if you wanna do it quicker, just keep track of the submission time, than you can easily sort the results by submission time

An enhancement you could also provide is to inform a user that the post has been updated since he opened it on the moment he wants to send his edits, by comparing version / submission time with the post he downloaded. He than can opt to look at it first and integrate the changes.

Comment: the first option is poor, dificult, and hackeable. The second one have a lot of alternatives, including AJAX to notify what others are doing

Comment: I agree the second option is the better choice, and optionally he could indeed use AJAX to get 'live updates', depending what better fit's in his site design. But since he said he used PHP and MySql, I wanted to focus on a solution that doesn't rely on AJAX :)

Comment: Uhm...but block the textbox (or better, the page where I can edit) is so easy : just looks at the code that I've posted in my topic! I think is just poor because another user can't edit it without the user has finished...

Comment: @markzzz your posted code is just sql and surounding PHP it don't blocks textareas (perhaps later code, not shown).  the matter is: who do revert the blocking update on the DB?  the one that caused it? and what about if he lives your app unatended or suddeny closed or ...? nobody can edit the record for a 20 minutes period. and what happens on a genuine 22 minutes edition?  I think the aproach as a bidding

Comment: Well, it is an option, it's just not very user friendly, imagine you want to edit something, but you have to wait 20 min, and while you're waiting the time expires and somebody else starts.. another 20 min might be lost. Essentially you could easily code an approach that keeps track of the time:
Install a hidden form field holding the time of the current edit, on submit just check wether it has changed (somebody else edited while you were editing), if yes: let the user view the new text, if no just post it

Answer (score 2):

the best approach is to invalidate the second edition, becouse you can react, advaicing the situation.
To manage in this way, you shuld track an incremental "editionID", so, both sessions recive the same editionID when they start editing, on the first submit (and on a transaction) if the editionID is the current you accept the edition (and increments editionID), otherwise (to the second browser) you give a message indicating the situation
Keep in mind that this approach is only valid in low colision probabilities case.

Answer (score 0):

the best approuch would be to lock the edit boxes through websockets as long as they are opened by some one other…